# How to decide which way to go up the Eiffel tower?

Tags: paris

You can take the stairs up to the second level, then lifts up to the top. Or you can take lifts straight to the top. I am thinking of avoiding the queue if I choose the stairs first. How much time can you save this way? I think it would be a lovely experience walking up the tower, but I wonder if it might be crowded?

What is the best way to gather the information I need to make this decision?

Comment: I have edited your question so you aren't asking us to decide for you. If your actual information-gathering questions are different, go ahead and edit some more yourself.

Comment: also, you may find some good advice in these questions and answers: https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=eiffel

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly, there is no direct way to the top, you have to change at the 2nd floor.

http://www.toureiffel.paris/en/what-to-see-on-the-eiffel-tower/going-up

"...Three lifts (North, East, and West pillars ) will take you up to the 1st and 2nd floors (115m). If you want to go to the top (276m), you need to change lifts at the 2nd floor..."

If you decide to walk up, remember that there are 700+ steps; might be better to take the elevator up and walk down.

In any case, the Tower is always crowded, but you can beat the crowd by reserving your tickets as early as possible (opens at 09:30)

The best way to get information is to use the Eiffel tower web site:

http://www.toureiffel.paris/en